# Sencha List with column lines

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-touch, extjs

How can we create a sencha list as given ie column lines

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your list in a similar manner to this:

```
list = {
  xtype: 'list',
  itemTpl: [
    '<table>',
      '<tr>',
        '<td class="first-child">{title}</td>',
        '<td>{title}</td>',
        '<td>{title}</td>',
        '<td>{title}</td>',
        '<td>{title}</td>',
        '<td class="last-child">{title}</td>',
      '</tr>',
    '</table>'          
  ],
  emptyText: '<div class="emptytext">Empty list.</div>'
};
```

Then use the following CSS to style the elements:

```
.x-list .x-list-item {
  min-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.x-list .x-list-item div table tr td {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15%;
}

.x-list .x-list-item div table {
  width: 100%;
}

.x-list .x-list-item div table tr .first-child {
  width: 25%;
}

.x-list .x-list-item div table tr .last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

That should give you something like this:

[image: Sencha List - Styled]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried it by giving borders each item in the list. But in display it will not be shown as a continuous line.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the padding on the containing div element?

Comment: @heyjii I've update my answer with the styling and modified the markup you'll need to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the excellent TouchGridPanel plugin by Mitchell Simoens

https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.TouchGridPanel

Comment: Hi @stan229 ,Thanks for your response. Can I use the GridPanel plugin for a sencha list?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by that. It's a wrapper of the DataView class, which is a superclass of the List type. There's an example on the github repo so take a look at it.